# tod_stub detector running error

Tags: ros, tod-detecting

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I encountered the following errors on running the tod_stub.

$ rosrun tod_stub detector -B t0001.bag

X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  26 (X_GLXMakeContextCurrent)
Serial number of failed request:  72
Current serial number in output stream:  72

Any comment would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Soonhac

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9262/tod_stub-detector-running-error/) by [Soonhac](https://answers.ros.org/users/225/soonhac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this issue by installing nvidia-glx-96.^^

Hope it would be helpful.

Soonhac

---

Originally posted by [Soonhac](https://answers.ros.org/users/225/soonhac/) with karma: 38 on 2011-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0